# Individual useState for multiple items

Tags: reactjs

I have 200 movies posters displayed in the same page. I want to know if there are individually "bookmarked" or not. I succeed to know if there are "bookmarked" when I am in the individual movie pages but in the main page where all movies are listed, the useState is the same for all movies. So if one movie is bookmarked, all movies will be displayed as bookmarked (true).

```
const [isBookmarked, setIsBookmarked] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  if (!currentUser) {
    return;
  }
  const unsubDoc = onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", currentUser.uid), (doc) => {
    setIsBookmarked( 
      doc.data()?.bookmarks.some((item: any) => item.id === item?.id)
    );
  });
  

  return () => unsubDoc();
}, [currentUser, item?.id]);
```

item.id is the movie id
doc.data()?.bookmarks gives the bookmark list

Do you have any suggestion what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: just take a look at this comparison: `item.id === item.id` which `item` is the one from the array, and which one is from the component?